# Time-based workflow, total queued limits

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I've read the documentation and it is clear that there are execution limits. I am more interested in the total gross numbers of time-based actions that are queued at a time. I.e. I undestand that if I schedule 1200 to be executed at a certain hour only 1000 will, 200 the next hour, but I want to know what happens if I schedule 12000 or 120000.

The question has been already asked but there were no answers, please provide a doc (if any) or even better your project experience! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this Help Doc [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US), under Limitations,

> - Time triggers don’t support minutes or seconds.
> - Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and 6:00 PM.

So, in the scenario you ask about, once the time triggers started to fire, you'd see 1000 records per hour. It would take you 12 hours to process 12,000 time-based-workflow records and up to 120 hours to process 120,000 time-based workflow records.

Additionally, you'll want to refer to knowledge article titled [Time Based Workflow Execution Interval is 15 minutes](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000231089&language=en_US) which has a somewhat misleading title as the last line below seems to give the definitive answer to your question.

> Salesforce users have an option to Monitor their time based workflow actions pending in the queue. In order to do that, they can follow these steps:
>
> - From Setup, enter Time-Based Workflow in the Quick Find box, then select Time-Based Workflow.
> - Click Search to view all pending actions for any active workflow rules, or set the filter criteria and click Search to view only the pending actions that match the criteria.
> - You will see the scheduled time-dependent workflow actions with Scheduled Date field specifying a certain date and time.
>
> **Time based workflow actions will not always execute at the exact time displayed in the Monitoring setup menu.**
>
> Instead, they are batched and executed every 15 minutes. Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers still apply. Therefore the expectation for the execution of time based workflow actions should be within 15 minutes of the scheduled time ***unless the Time Trigger per hour limit is exceeded, which will push the batch to the next hour.***

Also note that 1000/hr is for Unlimited and Performance Editions. EE has a limit of 500/hr as per the chart below:

```
Professional Edition    Enterprise Edition  Developer Edition   Unlimited and Performance Edition
        250                    500                   50                1,000
```

Comment: ok, the documentation is clear about what happens and no limits are cited, I was curious to know if someone actually tested it in practice (I've learned the hard way not to trust assumptions like: no limits are cited, then there are no limits)

Comment: I don't know why someone would want to test 12,000 records. Feel free to test and let us know what you find. The behavior is clearly defined.

Comment: "test" was not the correct word, I am sorry, I was wondering if someone actually used the time based workflows for large amounts of records in an actual implementation and if there are other details to take into account other than "there are execution limits which will delay the execution of the triggered actions" (which is very clear in the docs).